# 301 redirect from legacy site to cakephp site using routes.php and query string

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I was looking to build rules to redirect URLs from an old site to a brand new one built with CakePHP 2.5

Originally I was going to write .htaccess rules (though which one of the 3 to use isn't entirely clear) until it occurred to me that I should be able to create 301 redirect rules in routes.php as the [Routing page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) explains.

Unfortunately, though it's rather straightforward to setup rules that redirect www.example.com/page.php to www.example.com/page, it's a little more tricky to setup rules for URLs containing a query string.

For instance, I've been trying to redirect pages that contain pagination that tend to be formed like www.example.com/things/index/page:1 unfortunately, when the original page is formed like www.example.com/things_page.php?page_no=1 I can redirect it to www.example.com/things but I can't carry over the pagination. For this I used:

> `Router::redirect('/things_page.php?page_no=:page', array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'index', ':page' => 'page:[0-9]+'),array('persist' => true, 'status' => 301));`

from what I gathered mostly around similar topics on SO. Unfortunately, I can't get my head around getting the framework to interpret that query string as data to be used for the redirected url.

I read somewhere that it wasn't in fact possible in Cake to translate query strings into a clean path that Cake can interpret in the Router::redirect() statement but that strikes me as odd given that I can't be a unique case where I need old links to be translated into a Cake compatible path.

If I could avoid the .htaccess route I would prefer to do so for ease of maintenance but if that's the only way I would need to figure out which of the 3 .htaccess files to edit.

Cheers

Edit:
In the end I found a compromise in a French forum which suggests putting a rule in the beforefilter() function of the AppController like so:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
   if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'view', $_GET['id']));.
   }
}
```

I complemented my code with a string search of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to isolate the things_page.php for when multiple pages use the same $_GET variable. It's a bit crude but it works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is still not supported, I think the follwing ticket is kinda about that issue, not quite sure though:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2120**

Unless there is no support for this, you'll have to go with `.htaccess`, and the one that you should use to handle the redirects is the one in the `webroot` folder, ie `app/webroot/.htaccess`.